# INSERT query for python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list called mylist generated it results in (1, 2, 3, 4)

Is there a good way to write a query to just use the whole list as the Values.

The only way I know how to do it is

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s') % (mylist[0],mylist[1],mylist[2],mylist[3])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
"INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')" % tuple(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice way to do it using format:

```
"INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES ('{0[0]}','{0[1]}','{0[2]}','{0[3]}')".format(mylist)
```

Comment: You cane use the splat operator to avoid having to dereference each element: `('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')".format(*mylist)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how long your tuple is, you can do it in a more general fashion:

```
valuesstr = "("
for i in range(0,len(mylist)):             # Do this once for every list item.
  valuesstr += "'" + str(mylist[i]) + "'"  # Add a value automatically.
  if i+1 < len(mylist):                    # See if we've reached the end yet.
    valuesstr += ","                       # Add separating commas.
valuesstr += ")"

querystr = "INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES %s" % (valuesstr)
```

But if you know there will always be four items, the other answers are easier.